# How to give a user permission to create and write into files in bash?

Tags: python, linux, apache, bash, apache2

I am using an `apache` web server. I have an html file and a Python script located at var/www/myfolder. I am submitting a form through the html file which is handled by my Python script (when the submit button is clicked). But once handling the form, my Python script executes an external command.

When the Python script call `os.system("ls -l > temp.txt")`, I get a permission denied error. The problem is that the user `apache2` doesn't have the permission to create files. I also don't know the password for `apache2` so I can't use sudo.

Is there any way that I can give `apache2` permission to create temporary files?

**Edit 1:**

I get this warning before the permission denied error: `WARNING: HOME is not set, using root: /`

Comment: 1) this is not a programming question. 2) what you seem to be doing could potentially be very dangerous and without more specific information, it will be hard to give a good answer.

Comment: @hop This is for internal use only.

Comment: that is never a good reason to be sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

If the user `apache2` does not have any write permissions on the folder then it cannot create/modify files in that folder. However you can try creating files in `'/tmp/'` or in apache2's home folder. You can get apache2's home folder from 
`os.path.expanduser('~')`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I updated the question. I get this warning before the permission denied error: `WARNING: HOME is not set, using root: /`

Comment: @Alias Are you running this locally in your system. Do you have root access?

Comment: I don't have root access. I'm running this remotely from the Apache web server.

Comment: @Aias , no root access and no HOME folder. I don't think writing to disk is an optioin for your. You might have to search for alternative methods for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing to files, you can use a database. While this will also require giving rights to "apache2" user to access the database, it is more secure solution, and you can freely ask the server administrator to do that. Even small web sites use databases. You can start with Sqlite if your web service doesn't need big throughput.